# Why does scrapy repeatedly scrape one result only?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Please help me on this problem: the following spider code is expected to return all the listed jobs of the start_url. However, it only return many copies of the first job. Xpath codes are correctly tested in "Xpath Checker".  What is wrong?  Thanks for your input!

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Testjobs.items import TestjobsItem, TestjobsItemLoader

class TestjobSpider(Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ['http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org/']
    start_urls = [
        'http://careers.pathologyjobstoday.org/jobseeker/search/results'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)  
        sites = hxs.xpath('//tr[contains(@id, "jt_jobrow_")]') 

        for site in sites:
            il = TestjobsItemLoader(response=response, selector=site)
            il.add_xpath('title', 'normalize-space(//div[@class="jt_jobs_title"]/text())') 
            yield il.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your "inner" XPath *context-specific* by prepending a dot:

```
normalize-space(.//div[@class="jt_jobs_title"]/text())
            HERE^
```